# Java function to submit to SVN

Tags: java, svn, repository

Im trying to write a java function for a GUI that will let the user submit something to an online repository. Just like tortoisesvn does... Any thoughts or tutorials on how I should go about this?

Comment: An SVN repo can be access in many different ways.  The first one that comes to mind is SVNKit, though I've never used it.  SVNKit might be a bit overkill for your uses, but I'm sure there's a smaller, less capable library out there somewhere too.

Answer (score 3):

A google of "Java SVN" directly lead me to http://svnkit.com/documentation.html.